# Select last row of a table

Tags: sql

In my database table I have 40 rows, I want to select the last row id(primary key) so I used below code but instead of 40 it returns 14 what to do?

```
$num = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM result ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: Not possible with the query you showed, if your largest id is actually 40. Your error is someplace else, maybe something like you aren't looking at the correct version of your PHP file

Comment: of what type is your pk?

Comment: That query _will_ return the row with the highest id, even if it wasn't the last row inserted, owing to `ORDER BY id DESC`.

Comment: Check without the `limit 1`. Is your data returned in the correct order?

Comment: when i echo it, it return Resource #14

Comment: Are you sure you are selecting from correct table

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the order by is sorting lexically,
convert the id to int.

try this:

```
$num = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM result ORDER BY cast(ID as unsigned) DESC LIMIT 1");
```

here's fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e214/1

http://www.acrobatfaq.com/atbref5/index/ObjectsConcepts/Codingconventions/Sorting-lexicalandnumeri.html

Comment: when i echo it, it return Resource #14

Comment: provide structure of your table 'result'

Comment: two columns, id and username, i want to select id of last man how registered

Comment: then you can use last insert id function http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM result
```

Comment: when i echo it, it return Resource #14